# AWS Client VPN (OpenVPN) Mac user can connect but loses internet access; works on Win10

Tags: vpn, openvpn, mac-osx

I have a Mac user (macOS Catalina, 10.15.7) that can connect to our AWS Client VPN but loses wider internet access when they do so. The user is not technical, remote and I am not a Mac user and have no Mac to test this on.

The AWS Client VPN retains access on Windows 10 (19041) with OpenVPN Client and the AWS Client. We are using the same configuration file.

The VPN is there for protecting users when on unknown networks, so is a pass through. The user does not need access to our AWS resources.

When the VPN is active, I need all traffic to route through it. I believe the pertinent line (full log below) is:

```
2020-11-24 16:14:23.404 +00:00 [DBG] CM received: >LOG:1606234460,,PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,route-gateway 10.0.5.33,topology subnet,ping 1,ping-restart 20,ifconfig 10.0.5.34 255.255.255.224'
```

This is the AWS Client VPN server telling the client that all traffic must go through the gateway (`redirect-gateway def1`).

The Mac has no other VPN tunnels active.

Given that the user is not technical and I can only do video screen share if they are disconnected from the VPN, what steps should I take to resolve this?

### Full Connection Log

From the AWS Mac Client. Names changed to protect the innocent.

```
2020-11-24 16:12:46.578 +00:00 [INF] Logger initialized
2020-11-24 16:12:46.795 +00:00 [INF] Current OS Information:
2020-11-24 16:12:46.798 +00:00 [INF] Platform: "Unix"
2020-11-24 16:12:46.805 +00:00 [INF] Version String: Unix 19.6.0.0
2020-11-24 16:12:46.808 +00:00 [INF] OS description: Unix 19.6.0.0
2020-11-24 16:12:46.808 +00:00 [INF] OSX detected.
2020-11-24 16:12:47.117 +00:00 [DBG] Auto culture: en-GB Auto UI culture: en-GB
2020-11-24 16:12:47.286 +00:00 [DBG] openVpnExePath: /Applications/AWS VPN Client/AWS VPN Client.app/Contents/Resources/openvpn/acvc-openvpn
2020-11-24 16:12:47.286 +00:00 [DBG] helperToolExePath: /Applications/AWS VPN Client/AWS VPN Client.app/Contents/Resources/AWS VPN Client/Contents/MacOS/ACVCHelperTool
2020-11-24 16:12:47.293 +00:00 [INF] No existing profile store. Create an empty one in /Users/username/.config/AWSVPNClient/ConnectionProfiles
2020-11-24 16:12:47.315 +00:00 [INF] Saving profile store to /Users/username/.config/AWSVPNClient/ConnectionProfiles
2020-11-24 16:12:47.639 +00:00 [DBG] macOS viewDidLoad
2020-11-24 16:12:48.452 +00:00 [DBG] Current metadata schema version is 1, which is less or equal to current supported version: 1. 
2020-11-24 16:14:09.349 +00:00 [INF] Adding profile with name: XXX London, OpenVPN config file: /Users/username/Downloads/Open VPN Configuration File (1).ovpn
2020-11-24 16:14:09.359 +00:00 [INF] Validating OpenVPN config /Users/username/Downloads/Open VPN Configuration File (1).ovpn
2020-11-24 16:14:09.361 +00:00 [INF] File size of /Users/username/Downloads/Open VPN Configuration File (1).ovpn: 4564 bytes
2020-11-24 16:14:09.362 +00:00 [INF] Validating schema for OpenVPN config: /Users/username/Downloads/Open VPN Configuration File (1).ovpn
2020-11-24 16:14:09.386 +00:00 [INF] Successfully validated /Users/username/Downloads/Open VPN Configuration File (1).ovpn
2020-11-24 16:14:09.387 +00:00 [INF] Copying OpenVPN config to application local with name: XXX London, from source: /Users/username/Downloads/Open VPN Configuration File (1).ovpn
2020-11-24 16:14:09.394 +00:00 [INF] For OpenVPN config: /Users/username/Downloads/Open VPN Configuration File (1).ovpn, CvpnEndpointId: cvpn-endpoint-061a750f73ce6c477, CvpnEndpointRegion: eu-west-2
2020-11-24 16:14:09.400 +00:00 [INF] Saving profile store to /Users/username/.config/AWSVPNClient/ConnectionProfiles
2020-11-24 16:14:15.202 +00:00 [INF] Saving profile store to /Users/username/.config/AWSVPNClient/ConnectionProfiles
2020-11-24 16:14:15.211 +00:00 [INF] Connecting /Users/username/.config/AWSVPNClient/OpenVpnConfigs/XXX London 
2020-11-24 16:14:15.219 +00:00 [DBG] validationString: /Users/username/.config/AWSVPNClient/OpenVpnConfigs/XXX London
1606234465
2020-11-24 16:14:15.418 +00:00 [INF] Starting OpenVpn process
2020-11-24 16:14:15.421 +00:00 [DBG] Starting process
2020-11-24 16:14:15.453 +00:00 [DBG] Start to read process output
2020-11-24 16:14:18.826 +00:00 [DBG] End reading process output
2020-11-24 16:14:18.884 +00:00 [DBG] Helper app --init output: Kill success.
2020-11-24 16:14:18.884 +00:00 [DBG] Connecting using command /Applications/AWS VPN Client/AWS VPN Client.app/Contents/Resources/AWS VPN Client/Contents/MacOS/ACVCHelperTool --start -c "/Users/username/.config/AWSVPNClient/OpenVpnConfigs/current_connection.txt" -p "/Users/username/.config/AWSVPNClient/acvc-8096.txt"
2020-11-24 16:14:18.884 +00:00 [DBG] Starting process
2020-11-24 16:14:18.889 +00:00 [DBG] Start to read process output
2020-11-24 16:14:19.540 +00:00 [DBG] End reading process output
2020-11-24 16:14:19.594 +00:00 [DBG] Helper app --start output: Start success.
2020-11-24 16:14:19.635 +00:00 [INF] Connecting to management interface... host 127.0.0.1, port 8096
2020-11-24 16:14:19.652 +00:00 [DBG] Socket connected
2020-11-24 16:14:19.652 +00:00 [DBG] Starting to listen to management port
2020-11-24 16:14:19.656 +00:00 [DBG] Called isAliveProcess
2020-11-24 16:14:19.667 +00:00 [INF] Received bytes: 15
2020-11-24 16:14:19.668 +00:00 [DBG] Message marshalling complete
2020-11-24 16:14:19.675 +00:00 [DBG] CM received: ENTER PASSWORD:
2020-11-24 16:14:19.678 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: ENTER PASSWORD:
2020-11-24 16:14:19.679 +00:00 [DBG] Port needs password to connect
2020-11-24 16:14:19.680 +00:00 [DBG] Sending port password
2020-11-24 16:14:19.683 +00:00 [INF] Begin receive init again
2020-11-24 16:14:19.683 +00:00 [INF] Received bytes: 105
2020-11-24 16:14:19.684 +00:00 [DBG] Message marshalling complete
2020-11-24 16:14:19.684 +00:00 [DBG] CM received: SUCCESS: password is correct
>INFO:OpenVPN Management Interface Version 1 -- type 'help' for more info

2020-11-24 16:14:19.684 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: SUCCESS: password is correct
2020-11-24 16:14:19.684 +00:00 [DBG]  ONE lineSUCCESS: password is correct
2020-11-24 16:14:19.684 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >INFO:OpenVPN Management Interface Version 1 -- type 'help' for more info
2020-11-24 16:14:19.686 +00:00 [DBG] Asking for real-time state and log notifications.
2020-11-24 16:14:19.686 +00:00 [DBG] Waiting fixed time for response.
2020-11-24 16:14:19.688 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: 
2020-11-24 16:14:19.688 +00:00 [DBG]  APPEND line
2020-11-24 16:14:19.688 +00:00 [INF] Begin receive init again
2020-11-24 16:14:19.688 +00:00 [INF] Received bytes: 134
2020-11-24 16:14:19.688 +00:00 [DBG] Message marshalling complete
2020-11-24 16:14:19.689 +00:00 [DBG] CM received: SUCCESS: real-time state notification set to ON
SUCCESS: real-time log notification set to ON
>LOG:1606234459,D,MANAGEMENT: CMD ''

2020-11-24 16:14:19.689 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: SUCCESS: real-time state notification set to ON
2020-11-24 16:14:19.689 +00:00 [DBG] Response recieved for: state on
2020-11-24 16:14:19.690 +00:00 [DBG] Assume real-time state notifications are on. Received: SUCCESS: real-time state notification set to ON
2020-11-24 16:14:19.690 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: SUCCESS: real-time log notification set to ON
2020-11-24 16:14:19.690 +00:00 [DBG] Response recieved for: log on
2020-11-24 16:14:19.690 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234459,D,MANAGEMENT: CMD ''
2020-11-24 16:14:19.692 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: 
2020-11-24 16:14:19.693 +00:00 [DBG]  APPEND line
2020-11-24 16:14:19.693 +00:00 [INF] Begin receive init again
2020-11-24 16:14:20.811 +00:00 [INF] Received bytes: 168
2020-11-24 16:14:20.811 +00:00 [DBG] Message marshalling complete
2020-11-24 16:14:20.812 +00:00 [DBG] CM received: >LOG:1606234460,,MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1606234460,GET_CONFIG,,,,,,
>STATE:1606234460,GET_CONFIG,,,,,,
>LOG:1606234460,,SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)

2020-11-24 16:14:20.812 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234460,,MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1606234460,GET_CONFIG,,,,,,
2020-11-24 16:14:20.812 +00:00 [DBG] CM received state: >LOG:1606234460,,MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1606234460,GET_CONFIG,,,,,,
2020-11-24 16:14:20.813 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >STATE:1606234460,GET_CONFIG,,,,,,
2020-11-24 16:14:20.813 +00:00 [DBG] CM received state: >STATE:1606234460,GET_CONFIG,,,,,,
2020-11-24 16:14:20.813 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234460,,SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
2020-11-24 16:14:20.813 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: 
2020-11-24 16:14:20.813 +00:00 [DBG]  APPEND line
2020-11-24 16:14:20.813 +00:00 [INF] Begin receive init again
2020-11-24 16:14:23.404 +00:00 [INF] Received bytes: 1978
2020-11-24 16:14:23.404 +00:00 [DBG] Message marshalling complete
2020-11-24 16:14:23.404 +00:00 [DBG] CM received: >LOG:1606234460,,PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,route-gateway 10.0.5.33,topology subnet,ping 1,ping-restart 20,ifconfig 10.0.5.34 255.255.255.224'
>LOG:1606234460,,OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
>LOG:1606234460,,OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
>LOG:1606234460,,OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
>LOG:1606234460,,OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
>LOG:1606234460,,Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
>LOG:1606234460,,Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
>LOG:1606234460,,ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.0.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=en0 HWADDR=d4:61:9d:2c:1b:d8
>LOG:1606234460,,Opening utun (connect(AF_SYS_CONTROL)): Resource busy (errno=16)
>LOG:1606234460,,Opening utun (connect(AF_SYS_CONTROL)): Resource busy (errno=16)
>LOG:1606234460,I,Opened utun device utun2
>LOG:1606234460,D,do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
>LOG:1606234460,,MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1606234460,ASSIGN_IP,,10.0.5.34,,,,
>STATE:1606234460,ASSIGN_IP,,10.0.5.34,,,,
>LOG:1606234460,I,/sbin/ifconfig utun2 delete
>LOG:1606234460,I,NOTE: Tried to delete pre-existing tun/tap instance -- No Problem if failure
>LOG:1606234460,I,/sbin/ifconfig utun2 10.0.5.34 10.0.5.34 netmask 255.255.255.224 mtu 1500 up
>LOG:1606234460,,/sbin/route add -net 10.0.5.32 10.0.5.34 255.255.255.224
>LOG:1606234460,I,/Applications/AWS VPN Client/AWS VPN Client.app/Contents/Resources/openvpn/client.up -o -f utun2 1500 1549 10.0.5.34 255.255.255.224 init
>LOG:1606234463,,/sbin/route add -net 18.134.186.180 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.255
>LOG:1606234463,,/sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 10.0.5.33 128.0.0.0
>LOG:1606234463,,/sbin/route add -net 128.0.0.0 10.0.5.33 128.0.0.0
>LOG:1606234463,W,WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
>LOG:1606234463,I,Initialization Sequence Completed

2020-11-24 16:14:23.404 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234460,,PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,route-gateway 10.0.5.33,topology subnet,ping 1,ping-restart 20,ifconfig 10.0.5.34 255.255.255.224'
2020-11-24 16:14:23.405 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234460,,OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
2020-11-24 16:14:23.405 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234460,,OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
2020-11-24 16:14:23.405 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234460,,OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
2020-11-24 16:14:23.405 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234460,,OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
2020-11-24 16:14:23.405 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234460,,Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
2020-11-24 16:14:23.405 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234460,,Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
2020-11-24 16:14:23.405 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234460,,ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.0.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=en0 HWADDR=d4:61:9d:2c:1b:d8
2020-11-24 16:14:23.405 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234460,,Opening utun (connect(AF_SYS_CONTROL)): Resource busy (errno=16)
2020-11-24 16:14:23.405 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234460,,Opening utun (connect(AF_SYS_CONTROL)): Resource busy (errno=16)
2020-11-24 16:14:23.405 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234460,I,Opened utun device utun2
2020-11-24 16:14:23.405 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234460,D,do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
2020-11-24 16:14:23.406 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234460,,MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1606234460,ASSIGN_IP,,10.0.5.34,,,,
2020-11-24 16:14:23.406 +00:00 [DBG] CM received state: >LOG:1606234460,,MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1606234460,ASSIGN_IP,,10.0.5.34,,,,
2020-11-24 16:14:23.406 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >STATE:1606234460,ASSIGN_IP,,10.0.5.34,,,,
2020-11-24 16:14:23.406 +00:00 [DBG] CM received state: >STATE:1606234460,ASSIGN_IP,,10.0.5.34,,,,
2020-11-24 16:14:23.406 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234460,I,/sbin/ifconfig utun2 delete
2020-11-24 16:14:23.406 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234460,I,NOTE: Tried to delete pre-existing tun/tap instance -- No Problem if failure
2020-11-24 16:14:23.406 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234460,I,/sbin/ifconfig utun2 10.0.5.34 10.0.5.34 netmask 255.255.255.224 mtu 1500 up
2020-11-24 16:14:23.406 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234460,,/sbin/route add -net 10.0.5.32 10.0.5.34 255.255.255.224
2020-11-24 16:14:23.406 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234460,I,/Applications/AWS VPN Client/AWS VPN Client.app/Contents/Resources/openvpn/client.up -o -f utun2 1500 1549 10.0.5.34 255.255.255.224 init
2020-11-24 16:14:23.406 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234463,,/sbin/route add -net 18.134.186.180 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.255
2020-11-24 16:14:23.406 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234463,,/sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 10.0.5.33 128.0.0.0
2020-11-24 16:14:23.406 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234463,,/sbin/route add -net 128.0.0.0 10.0.5.33 128.0.0.0
2020-11-24 16:14:23.406 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234463,W,WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
2020-11-24 16:14:23.407 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234463,I,Initialization Sequence Completed
2020-11-24 16:14:23.407 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: 
2020-11-24 16:14:23.407 +00:00 [DBG]  APPEND line
2020-11-24 16:14:23.407 +00:00 [INF] Begin receive init again
2020-11-24 16:14:23.407 +00:00 [INF] Received bytes: 165
2020-11-24 16:14:23.407 +00:00 [DBG] Message marshalling complete
2020-11-24 16:14:23.407 +00:00 [DBG] CM received: >LOG:1606234463,,MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1606234463,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,10.0.5.34,18.134.186.180,443,,
>STATE:1606234463,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,10.0.5.34,18.134.186.180,443,,

2020-11-24 16:14:23.407 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >LOG:1606234463,,MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1606234463,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,10.0.5.34,18.134.186.180,443,,
2020-11-24 16:14:23.407 +00:00 [DBG] CM received state: >LOG:1606234463,,MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1606234463,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,10.0.5.34,18.134.186.180,443,,
2020-11-24 16:14:23.408 +00:00 [DBG] Management port password authenticated.
2020-11-24 16:14:23.410 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: >STATE:1606234463,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,10.0.5.34,18.134.186.180,443,,
2020-11-24 16:14:23.410 +00:00 [DBG] CM received state: >STATE:1606234463,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,10.0.5.34,18.134.186.180,443,,
2020-11-24 16:14:23.414 +00:00 [DBG] Management port password authenticated.
2020-11-24 16:14:23.414 +00:00 [DBG] Destroyed management port password file on authentication.
2020-11-24 16:14:23.414 +00:00 [DBG] CM processsing: 
2020-11-24 16:14:23.414 +00:00 [DBG]  APPEND line
2020-11-24 16:14:23.414 +00:00 [INF] Begin receive init again
2020-11-24 16:14:33.934 +00:00 [DBG]  BeginConnectionDetails
2020-11-24 16:14:33.945 +00:00 [INF] Received bytes: 222
2020-11-24 16:14:33.945 +00:00 [DBG] Message marshalling complete
2020-11-24 16:14:33.948 +00:00 [DBG] CM received: >LOG:1606234473,D,MANAGEMENT: CMD 'status'
OpenVPN STATISTICS
Updated,Tue Nov 24 16:14:33 2020
TUN/TAP read bytes,588
TUN/TAP write bytes,0
TCP/UDP read bytes,3601
TCP/UDP write bytes,4061
Auth read bytes,176
END
```

### Edit 1 - Routing Tables

#### Connected Via OpenVPN Connect via Starbucks Wifi

No internet connection.

```
Internet:
Destination    Gateway      Flags    Netif Expire
0/1            10.0.4.33     UGSc     utun2    
default        192.168.99.1    UGSc      en0    
10.0.4.32/27   10.0.4.35     UGSc     utun2    
10.0.4.33      10.0.4.35     UHr     utun2    
18.135.71.242/32  192.168.99.1    UGSc      en0    
127            127.0.0.1     UCS      lo0    
127.0.0.1      127.0.0.1     UH       lo0    
128.0/1        10.0.4.33     UGSc     utun2    
169.254        link#4       UCS      en0   !
192.168.99     link#4       UCS      en0   !
192.168.99.1/32   link#4       UCS      en0   !
192.168.99.1      c:8d:db:1a:34:8  UHLWIir    en0  1196
192.168.99.235/32 link#4       UCS      en0   !
192.168.99.255    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff UHLWbI     en0   !
224.0.0/4     link#4       UmCS      en0   !
224.0.0.251       1:0:5e:0:0:fb   UHmLWI     en0    
239.255.255.250   1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa  UHmLWI     en0    
255.255.255.255/32  link#4       UCS      en0   !
255.255.255.255     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff UHLWbI     en0   !

Internet6:
Destination               Gateway             Flags     Netif Expire
default                   fe80::%utun0        UGcI     utun0    
default                   fe80::%utun1        UGcI     utun1    
::1                       ::1                 UHL       lo0    
fe80::%lo0/64             fe80::1%lo0        UcI       lo0    
fe80::1%lo0               link#1              UHLI      lo0    
fe80::%en0/64             link#4             UCI       en0    
fe80::1c8a:3291:7867:e3d3%en0      d4:61:9d:2c:1b:d8        UHLI      lo0    
fe80::%awdl0/64           link#8             UCI      awdl0    
fe80::c4eb:e3ff:fe52:cd45%awdl0     c6:eb:e3:52:cd:45        UHLI      lo0    
fe80::%llw0/64            link#9             UCI      llw0    
fe80::c4eb:e3ff:fe52:cd45%llw0     c6:eb:e3:52:cd:45        UHLI      lo0    
fe80::%utun0/64           fe80::9ef:48ff:d4a1:367d%utun0 UcI      utun0    
fe80::9ef:48ff:d4a1:367d%utun0     link#10             UHLI      lo0    
fe80::%utun1/64           fe80::425f:be76:db08:d4c%utun1 UcI      utun1    
fe80::425f:be76:db08:d4c%utun1     link#11             UHLI      lo0    
ff01::%lo0/32             ::1               UmCI      lo0    
ff01::%en0/32             link#4             UmCI      en0    
ff01::%awdl0/32           link#8             UmCI     awdl0    
ff01::%llw0/32            link#9             UmCI      llw0    
ff01::%utun0/32           fe80::9ef:48ff:d4a1:367d%utun0 UmCI     utun0    
ff01::%utun1/32           fe80::425f:be76:db08:d4c%utun1 UmCI     utun1    
ff02::%lo0/32             ::1               UmCI      lo0    
ff02::%en0/32             link#4             UmCI      en0    
ff02::%awdl0/32           link#8             UmCI     awdl0    
ff02::%llw0/32            link#9             UmCI      llw0    
ff02::%utun0/32           fe80::9ef:48ff:d4a1:367d%utun0 UmCI     utun0    
ff02::%utun1/32           fe80::425f:be76:db08:d4c%utun1 UmCI     utun1
```

### Edit 2 - Removing IPv6 via Config

AWS Client VPN does not support IPv6 (although not explicitly, you won't find it in any documentation). I cannot get the remote user to mess with routing tables or switch it off because they are not technical and I need to roll out the VPN to other users.

I added the following lines to the config to filter out the IPv6 traffic. The route tables above looked the same.

```
pull-filter ignore "ifconfig-ipv6 "
pull-filter ignore "route-ipv6 "
```

Comment: Have you tried editing /etc/hosts and adding the gateway manually?  It's supposed to work regardless, but I had a similar problem (different VPN) that I solved by adding routes to the host file.

Comment: What's your user's routing table look like? Try `netstat -nr` in terminal to display it.

Comment: @DavidWatson thanks for the feedback - my user is not technical and I am not a Mac user, I cannot ask them to perform host updates over the phone.

Comment: @mforsetti Thank you, I managed to get the route table when the VPN is connected but there is no gateway access ⬆

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Changing IPv6 from automatic to link local only or disabling IPv6 on my LAN resolved this for me. Win10 didn't have an issue as IPv6 was disabled. mforsetti's idea to look at the routing table helped me see that IPv6 was the culprit in my case

Comment: Welcome to SE! Thank you, that's helpful but these are not instructions I can follow, nor can I explain them down a phone to a remote user, so it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @DrRobLang this is easy to google.  In summary, click open the network window, click advanced for the appropriate network, tcp/ip tab on top, then configure IPv6 dropdown to Link-local only on Monterey (and probably most others).

Answer (score 0):

Check your dns requests. The user without internet should have access to ping googles nameservers for example (8.8.8.8) but resolving the google.com dns name should fail (dig google.com).

If this is true you need to go into your AWS vpn client endpoints and allow the users access (via an authorization rule) to the subnet IP addresses the endpoint drops them into so that their host machines can use that subnets DNS server. If you don't want to do this then you will have to have the MAC users reconfigure their devices to point to the nameservers they actually want.